# Set up Gmail to work properly with Apple Mail

Tags: mail.app, gmail

1. I often can't find my sent mail in my Gmail account viewed on my Mac in Apple Mail. I did not set up these folders, but I have both a "Sent Mail" folder indented under a "Gmail" folder and a "Sent Messages (gmail [accountname])" folder in my Gmail account in Apple Mail. Sometimes a sent messages shows up in neither of those, but I can find it by searching for it.
2. Some incoming messages do not appear in my Inbox, but are in a box I did not set up labeled "Important."

How do I set the Gmail settings and filters to avoid these two problems?

Answer (score 5):

Besides Google's "official" guide to configure GMail with a desktop client (see Wheat Williams' answer) I think this guide is pretty good and helpful:

http://www.macworld.com/article/157846/2011/03/mailgmail.html

It' a detailed step-by-step guide an features several screenshots.

Regarding the sent messages (your first point):

> "Select the [Gmail] -> Sent Mail subfolder and choose Mailbox -> Use This Mailbox For -> Sent"

Comment: I have been looking for something like this for very long, thank you.

Comment: The correct link is http://www.macworld.com/article/1157846/mailgmail.html

Comment: Please just edit the question - everyone can edit things and should when they can correct something or make an answer better.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using POP or IMAP?

Google GMail has help documents for that that.

[POP configuration](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=180190&topic=12810)

[IMAP configuration](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78892#)